# JavaScript: variables for submitted input fields only have a value after F5 refresh

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, so I have this code here which is at the bottom of my question that prompts the user to enter a UserId, their first name, last name and birthday into the supplied input fields.

The most important part is that the code calculates the difference between the user's birthday and today's date in number of days. Then the number of days is printed to the page via the DOM like this:

```
let results2 = fname + " " + lname + ", " + "you have been breathing for " + daysDifference + " days!";
resultsDiv.innerHTML = results2;
```

The only problem is that when you click the accept button, the console logged variables are shown to be empty or undefined values and the DOM manipulated HTML outputs empty values as well. For whatever reason, you have to THEN refresh the page via F5 and click the accept button again in order for the console logged variables to output their correct values and for the DOM manipulated HTML to output the right stuff.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="forms">

<form action="/action_page.php">

  <label for="user">User Id:</label>
  <input type="text" id="user" name="user" required><br>

  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="firstname" name="fname" required><br>

  <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lname" required><br>

  <label for="birthday">Birthday:</label>
  <input type="date" id="birth" name="birthday" required><br>

  <input type="submit" id="submit-button" value="Accept">

</form>

</div>

<div>

<div id="results">



</div>

</div>

</div>

<script>

alert("Whenever you are ready; click the OK button and then please enter your first name, last name, a User ID and your birthdate (MM/DD/YYYY format) in their respective input fields on this website.");

let userid = document.getElementById("user").value;

function verifyUser() {

  const regex = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{8,12}$/;

  if (regex.test(userid)) {
    console.log("Valid UserId");
  } else {
    console.log("Invalid UserId");
  };

};

let fname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;

function verifyFirstName() {

  if (fname.trim() == "") {
    console.log("Invalid First Name");
  } else {
    console.log("Valid First Name");
  };

};

let lname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;

function verifyLastName() {

  if (lname.trim() == "") {
    console.log("Invalid Last Name");
  } else {
    console.log("Valid Last Name");
  };

};

today = new Date();
let birthDate = new Date(document.getElementById("birth").value);

let birthday = document.getElementById("birth").value;

function verifyBirthday() {

  if (birthday.trim() == "") {
    console.log("Invalid Birthday");
  } else {
    console.log("Valid Birthday");
  };

};

let daysDifference;

function daysDiff(birthDate) {

  let differenceMilliseconds = today.getTime() - birthDate.getTime();

   daysDifference = parseInt(differenceMilliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

  return daysDifference;

};

const resultsDiv = document.getElementById("results");

function daysResults() {

  if (daysDifference < (365 * 18)) {
    let results1 = "You are probably not old enough to take this class!";
    resultsDiv.innerHTML = results1;
  } else {
    let results2 = fname + " " + lname + ", " + "you have been breathing for " + daysDifference + " days!";
    resultsDiv.innerHTML = results2;
  }

}

document.getElementById('submit-button').addEventListener('click', 
  function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    verifyUser();
    verifyFirstName();
    console.log(fname);
    verifyLastName();
    console.log(lname);
    verifyBirthday()
    daysDiff(birthDate);
    console.log(daysDifference);
    daysResults();

  }
);

let str = "";

for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  document.write(str.padStart(i,"x") + "<br>");
} 

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm new to JS so I have no idea why this is happening. My assumption is that the inputted values are only set or updated whenever the accept button is clicked instead of it actively listening to the input fields being modified by the user.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required

Comment: Ok, I added required to the input fields but it doesn't fix my issue.

Comment: indeed, it's the whole form management that's wrong. and what are the asterixes at the end of the page for?

Comment: Your statements that fetch the values, like `let userid = document.getElementById("user").value)` need to be INSIDE the validation functions.  What you have will fetch their initial (empty) contents as the page is belig loaded, and then those variables are never updated again.  Those are static variables; they don't change as the fields change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch the field values every time you need to read them.  This seems to do what you want:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="forms">

<form action="/action_page.php">

  <label for="user">User Id:</label>
  <input type="text" id="user" name="user" required><br>

  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="firstname" name="fname" required><br>

  <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lname" required><br>

  <label for="birthday">Birthday:</label>
  <input type="date" id="birth" name="birthday" required><br>

  <input type="submit" id="submit-button" value="Accept">

</form>

</div>

<div>

<div id="results">

</div>

</div>

</div>

<script>

let userid = '';

function verifyUser() {

  userid = document.getElementById("user").value;
  const regex = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{8,12}$/;

  if (regex.test(userid)) {
    console.log("Valid UserId");
  } else {
    console.log("Invalid UserId");
  };

};

let fname = '';

function verifyFirstName() {

  fname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
  if (fname.trim() == "") {
    console.log("Invalid First Name");
  } else {
    console.log("Valid First Name");
  };

};

let lname = '';

function verifyLastName() {

  lname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
  if (lname.trim() == "") {
    console.log("Invalid Last Name");
  } else {
    console.log("Valid Last Name");
  };

};

let today = new Date();

function verifyBirthday() {

  birthDate = new Date(document.getElementById("birth").value);
  birthday = document.getElementById("birth").value;
  if (birthday.trim() == "") {
    console.log("Invalid Birthday");
  } else {
    console.log("Valid Birthday");
  };

};

let daysDifference;

function daysDiff(birthDate) {

  let differenceMilliseconds = today.getTime() - birthDate.getTime();

  daysDifference = parseInt(differenceMilliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

  return daysDifference;

};


function daysResults() {

  let resultsDiv = document.getElementById("results");
  let result='';
  if (daysDifference < (365 * 18)) {
    result = "You are probably not old enough to take this class!";
  } else {
    result = fname + " " + lname + ", " + "you have been breathing for " + daysDifference + " days!";
  }
  resultsDiv.innerHTML = result;
}

document.getElementById('submit-button').addEventListener('click', 
  function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    verifyUser();
    verifyFirstName();
    console.log(fname);
    verifyLastName();
    console.log(lname);
    verifyBirthday()
    daysDiff(birthDate);
    console.log(daysDifference);
    daysResults();
  }
);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No needs of so much JS code...

```js
const
  myForm  = document.querySelector('#my-form')
, one_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
, toDay   = new Date()
  ;
// set max date attribute
myForm.birthday.max = toDay.toISOString().split("T")[0];

myForm.addEventListener('submit', e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault();  // disable form submit just for testing
  
  myForm.daysCount.textContent = ( toDay.getTime() 
                                 - myForm.birthday.valueAsDate.getTime()
                                 ) / one_day;
  let data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(myForm).entries());
 
  console.clear();
  console.log( JSON.stringify(data) );
  });
```

```css
body {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 16px;
  }
fieldset {
  margin : 1rem;
  width  : 14rem;
  }
legend {
  font-weight   : bold;
  font-size     : 1.4rem;
  margin-bottom : .2rem;
  }
label {
  display    : block;
  margin-top : 0.8em;
  font-size  : .9rem;
  }
input:not([type=checkbox]) {
  display    : block;
  }
button {
  margin-top   : 1rem;
  margin-right : 1rem;
  width        : 40%;
  }
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" id="my-form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend> ? </legend>
    <label>
      User Id:
      <input  name="user" type="text" pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{8,12}$" required>
    </label>
    <label>
      First name:
      <input name="fname"  type="text" required>
    </label>
    <label>Last name:
      <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lname" required> 
    </label>
    <label>
      Birthday: 
      <input  name="birthday" type="date" max="" required>
    </label>

    <button type="submit"> Accept </button>
    <button type="reset" > Reset  </button>

    <output name="daysCount">_<output>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the mistake I made was not putting the input field value reads into the verify functions I made for them.

Also, the other mistake I made was not realizing that if you shouldn't use let when you want to change the value of a global variable inside of a function. If you do that, it will actually causes issues when you return that variable. So just do variable = whatever, don't include let.

Anyways, here's the final version of the code that I made for my project.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="forms">

<form action="/action_page.php">

  <label for="user">User Id:</label>
  <input type="text" id="user" name="user" required><br>

  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="firstname" name="fname" required><br>

  <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lname" required><br>

  <label for="birthday">Birthday:</label>
  <input type="date" id="birth" name="birthday" required><br>

  <input type="submit" id="submit-button" value="Accept">

</form>

</div>

<div>

<div id="results">



</div>

</div>

</div>

<script>

alert("Whenever you are ready; click the OK button and then please enter your first name, last name, a User ID and your birthdate (MM/DD/YYYY format) in their respective input fields on this website.");

let userid;

function verifyUser() {

  userid = document.getElementById("user").value;

  const regex = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{8,12}$/;

  if (regex.test(userid)) {
    console.log("VerifyUser Function: Your UserId is valid");
  } else {
    console.log("VerifyUser Function: Your UserId is invalid");
  };

  return userid;

};

let fname;

function verifyFirstName() {

  fname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;

  if (fname.trim() == "") {
    console.log("VerifyFirstName Function: Your first name is invalid");
  } else {
    console.log("VerifyFirstName Function: Your first name is valid");
  };

  return fname;

};

let lname;

function verifyLastName() {

  lname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;

  if (lname.trim() == "") {
    console.log("VerifyLastName Function: Your last name is invalid");
  } else {
    console.log("VerifyLastName Function: Your last name is valid");
  };

  return lname;

};

today = new Date();

let birthday;
let birthDate;

function verifyBirthday() {

  birthday = document.getElementById("birth").value;
  birthDate = new Date(document.getElementById("birth").value);

  if (birthday.trim() == "") {
    console.log("VerifyBirthday Function: Your birthday is invalid");
  } else {
    console.log("VerifyBirthday Function: Your birthday is valid");
  };

  return birthDate;

};

let daysDifference;

function daysDiff(birthDate) {

  let differenceMilliseconds = today.getTime() - birthDate.getTime();

  daysDifference = parseInt(differenceMilliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

  return daysDifference;

};

const resultsDiv = document.getElementById("results");

function daysResults() {

  if (daysDifference < (365 * 18)) {
    let results1 = "You are probably not old enough to take this class!";
    console.log("daysDifference Variable: You are probably not old enough to take this class!");
    resultsDiv.innerHTML = results1;
  } else {
    let results2 = fname + " " + lname + ", " + "you have been breathing for " + daysDifference + " days!";
    console.log("daysDifference Variable: " + fname + " " + lname + ", " + "you have been breathing for " + daysDifference + " days!");
    resultsDiv.innerHTML = results2;
  }

}

document.getElementById('submit-button').addEventListener('click', 
  function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    verifyUser();
    verifyFirstName();
    verifyLastName();
    verifyBirthday();
    daysDiff(birthDate);
    console.log("Accept Button: Your UserId is " + userid);
    console.log("Accept Button: Your first name is " + fname);
    console.log("Accept Button: Your last name is " + lname);
    console.log("Accept Button: Your Birthday is " + birthDate);
    console.log("Accept Button: The Difference in Days is " + daysDifference);
    daysResults();

  }
);

let str = "";

for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  document.write(str.padStart(i,"x") + "<br>");
} 

</script>

</body>
</html>
```